# Dynamic Rows and Table

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to implement a dynamic table but when the button is pressed to add a row the row is added but the input text box is not inserted in both cells.  Any idea how to solve this problem.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <table id="dataTable" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td height="27">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
            firstCell.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
            var element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "text";
            element.name = "txtbox[]";
            secondCell.appendChild(element);

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Not an answer, just an advice: have a look at datatables jquery plugin: http://datatables.net/ . If you just want to implement dynamic tables for a real-world application, it would be the best to use well-known high-quality component and save yourself hundreds of working hours. If you do it for academic purposes, still, it makes sense to learn source code (why not datatables?) to understand the complexity of the task and the useful design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another "input" element and append this into the thirdCell.

Try changing the last bit of your javascript function to this:

```
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.name = "txtbox1[]";

var element2 = document.createElement("input");
element2.type = "text";
element2.name = "txtbox2[]";

secondCell.appendChild(element1);
thirdCell.appendChild(element2);
```

[Shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/LqDGP/1/)

**Note:** Your `script` tag should go inside the `body` of the html.

Here is what the final code could look like:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <table id="dataTable" width="150px" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td height="27">
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
            firstCell.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
            var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
            var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);

            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "text";
            element1.name = "txtbox1[]";

            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox2[]";

            secondCell.appendChild(element1);
            thirdCell.appendChild(element2);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not written the code to add a new text element to the third column. Add the below mentioned code after "secondCell.appendChild(element);" section of your code:

```
var element2 = document.createElement("input");

element2.type = "text";

element2.name = "txtbox2[]";

thirdCell.appendChild(element2);
```